# Wifi in FreeBSD Live USB

Tags: wifi, freebsd, thinkpad

After using Linux for quite some time now I want to try out FreeBSD. I created a bootable USB stick and want to play around a bit in the live CD mode. The first problem I encounter is that I don't know how to get the wifi to work.

Running `sysctl net.wlan.devices` yields an empty `net.wlan.devices:`.

I guess this means that the module for my wifi-adapter is not loaded? Most of the stuff I find to enable wifi requires changing some configs and rebooting but I guess that's not that easy on a live USB.

Now my question is: How do I enable wifi? How do I know which module I need to load?

I am using a Thinkpad L480 (which is not listed [on the laptops page](https://wiki.freebsd.org/Laptops)). Is free BSD even compatible with it?

Comment: Does `dmesg -a` give some hints ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to ThinkPad L480 [Tech Specs](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-l/ThinkPad-L480/p/22TP2TBL480), it features Intel® Dual Band 8265 Wireless AC (2 x 2) wifi adapter, which should be supported by [iwm](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=iwm&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) driver.

You should be able to load driver and firmware at runtime without rebooting:

```
kldload if_iwm
kldload iwm8265fw
```

Check if they loaded successfully with `kldstat`. If modules aren't listed I guess you are out of luck until someone adds support for your card. If they are, read on.

The rest is nicely explained in [Wireless Networking](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-wireless.html) chapter of FreeBSD Handbook, here are exact lines you need:

```
ifconfig wlan0 create wlandev iwm0
ifconfig wlan0 up scan
```

You should be able to see list of wifi networks:

```
ifconfig wlan0 list scan
```

You will need to create `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` (assuming your wifi network is RSN/WPA2):

```
network={
 ssid="yournetwork"
 psk="yournetworkpass"
}
```

Append the following to the `/etc/rc.conf`:

```
wlans_ath0="wlan0"
ifconfig_wlan0="WPA DHCP"
```

Bring up the interface:

```
service netif restart
```

...and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try: `kldload if_iwm`

This loads the Intel 8000 series wifi driver