# How to connect to wifi in FreeBSD live CD

Tags: freebsd

I am trying to run a few tests with a FreeBSD live CD.

How can I connect to the WIFI? I have found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466986/wifi-in-freebsd-live-usb) already and [the documentation](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-wireless.html), but in all cases, I have to edit `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` -- but I cannot do that, it is a *Read-only file system*!

Is there any way around that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close. Look again in the FreeBSD Handbook at section [31.3.4.1.3.1. WPA-PSK](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-wireless.html) which shows how to do a manual association.

```
# wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

When associated you should then ask for an IP address if using DHCP:

```
# dhclient wlan0
```

But if you are using fixed addresses then you just set it:

```
# ifconfig wlan0 inet 192.168.0.100 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

So! Rather than using a config file in `/etc` you could place it anywhere. If memory serves me then `/tmp` is already mounted as [tmpfs(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tmpfs&sektion=5). If not - you can simply mount a location of your choice as `tmpfs` and place the configuration file there.

That is the manual way and should work. But if I remember correctly you can get networking running via `bsdinstall` on a live CD system. I have however not verified this recently.

Comment: Yeees! Nice. :-)